# recalculate multiple div sizes on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, window-resize

I have a div with a set of inpage links that is being fixed to the top of the window when it's scrolled to, but I need to adjust the code below so that it recalculates the outerHeight of the .featured-image and #mainNavPrimary divs when the window is resized. But am struggling as I'm new to javascript. This is my code that works just on load. Please help.

```
$("#devInpageLinks").affix({
  offset: {
    top: $(".featured-image").outerHeight(true) + $("#mainNavPrimary").outerHeight(true) - 68
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use 'resize' event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var refreshSizes = function() {
    $("#devInpageLinks").affix({offset: {top: $(".featured-image").outerHeight(true) + $("#mainNavPrimary").outerHeight(true) - 68 } });
  };
  // This will handle every resize event.
  $(window).resize(refreshSizes);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for trying. I've been trying something similar, but isn't working with this code.

Comment: Can you explain your problem with resize event handling? Are you using jQuery in your project? Without them you cannot use this code I've posted.

Comment: Yes, it's using jquery, and is working fine on page load, but adding a resize event just isn't working. So am a bit stuck

Comment: The issue seems to be to do with the height, which is currently using       ```min-height: calc(100vw * 0.4);``` in the css however if I add a fixed height of height:600px; it works. So it's this recalculation where an issue is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Give a look to "media queries" and "responsive design".
Basically you define in your CSS what your style is **depending on** the window size.

Comment: It has a responsive image at the top, so the image height changes on resize and so inpage nav affix position needs to be recalculated. So needs javascript

Comment: I don't understand how it has to be done in javascript and can't be done in CSS.